# difference between .equals() and ==

Tags: java, types, comparison

I don't know why after using .toString() and having our new String, we need only to use .equals instead of == when we want to compare. But other strings can be compared with ==. Why is that and what are the cases when we need == or equals?

Comment: Difference between the objects content (`equals`) and it's memory reference `==` - `equals` is a means by which you can compare two difference instance of an object to determine if they are (essentially) the same thing, it also allows for customisation of the pattern based on your objects needs

Comment: Ask yourself if you want to write code that seems to work, or if you want to write code that is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

> But other strings can be compared with ==.

They can't, actually.  Not reliably.

> Why is that and what are the cases when we need == or equals?

The cases when you need `==` do not exist.  The cases when you use `.equals` are 100% of the time.

(There are some cases where people may say that with string interning or other use cases, `==` suffices.  This is not actually a good reason, and you should never use `==`.)

Comment: So to avoid all problems with strings, i should only use equals

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `==` compares addresses and `.equals()` compares contents. Objects, like strings are reference types so even if they contain the same content, using `==` while comparing two strings may not always return the same outcome.

`.equals()` is a method that accepts the type `Object` and casts the value to the class and gets the instance's private members and compare the values.